# How can I trigger the click function on the chart, when I click on a point?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to trigger the chart click event, when I click on a point?

I am trying to have a consistent behavior, so I wonder if I can click on a point and in the click function of the point, call the chart click event.

Even better, if I can just disable altogether the click on the point; altho I use tooltip, so I guess that it won't work without points then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instaed of triggering, you can prepare a global functions and then call it in click point event.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            click: function (event) {
                chartClick();
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert('point click');
                        chartClick();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

function chartClick() {
    alert('chartClick');
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/233x5698/

Comment: Overall works, but not in my particular case. Is there no way to fake the click on it?

Comment: In this case you have no fake trigger, so let me know what you mean